# Threshold + Contours (video)

Tags: python, opencv

Basically, my program will detect moving objects in the video scene by using a method called (thresholding). But, i want to add findcontours feature into the program. I built this code from scratch. Now im stuck at 'findcontours' and 'drawcontours' part.

Problem:

1. Cant draw contours on detected objects (fixed)
2. ValueError: too many values to unpack (findcontours)

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
history = 150
varThreshold = 18
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()


while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    img_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck ? What is the issue? Kindly elaborate the question.

Comment: @ZdaR updated. Kindly help.

Comment: Replace `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` with `img_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

Comment: problem (1) fixed. Still no contours around detected objects.

Comment: You must verify that `fgmask ` is a single channel binary mask, try debugging the mask using `cv2.imwrite()` or `cv2.imshow()`